# unable to make a 2d array list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

this is my code in python I don't understand how to combine given output in a one single array (2d array)

code is:-

```
city = ["chennai","indore","mumbai","gwalior","kerla"]
temp =[20,30,40,35,25]
humidity =[70,35,60,40,80]
rainfall =[60,40,65,35,85]
population =[68,59,78,37,80]
def check(x):
    Max = max(x)
    Min = min(x)
    R = (Max - Min)/3
    R1 = Min+R
    R2 = R1+R
    DI=[]
    for i in x:
        if(i<R1):
            DI.append("Low")
        elif(i>R2):
            DI.append("High")
        else:
            DI.append("Moderate")

    print(DI)

check(temp)
check(rainfall)
check(humidity)
check(population)
```

and the output is :-

```
['Low', 'Moderate', 'High', 'High', 'Low']
['Moderate', 'Low', 'Moderate', 'Low', 'High']
['High', 'Low', 'Moderate', 'Low', 'High']
['High', 'Moderate', 'High', 'Low', 'High']
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: i want my output in an array form which is 4X5 matrix cointains the above data

Comment: @chrisz that will print the previous output and then `[None, None, None, None]`

Comment: @MoxieBall yeah, the function does not return anything. It just prints. To return what is desired with a list comprehension `return DI` needs to be added to the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 2D array in python is just a list of lists. List can be defined with some pretty simple syntax -- `a = [1,2,3,4]` defines `a` as the list `[1,2,3,4]`.

Your check function currently just prints the lists you make. If you want to keep the lists you make to use later, you need to `return` them, so that `a = check(temp)` will assign the value of `check(temp)` to the variable `a`.

If your check function returns the lists, you can create a list of your results with `results = [check(temp), check(rainfall), check(humidity), check(population)]`.

Comment: [['Low', 'Moderate', 'High', 'High', 'Low'], ['Moderate', 'Low', 'Moderate', 'Low', 'High'], ['High', 'Low', 'Moderate', 'Low', 'High'], ['High', 'Moderate', 'High', 'Low', 'High']]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-16a127b7acfa> in <module>()
     21 results = [check(temp), check(rainfall), check(humidity), check(population)]
     22 print(results)
---> 23 print(results[0,1])

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Comment: Yes, results[0,1] is not proper syntax, what is your question?

Comment: i cannot access data in the matrix as it takes whole "check(temp)" as a data

Comment: If you want to access the second element of the first list the syntax is `results[0][1]`. This answer is still correct, maybe read this https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html and do some experimentation with printing stuff like `type(results[0])` to learn more about lists.